# The double master phenomenon

Tags: raft, hashicorp

Imagine a cluster running on the Raft protocol that has numerous nodes running in completely two separated networks (i.e. AWS VPC). This cluster is running fine for a while and has exactly one master as expected. All of a sudden something goes wrongs and the connection between the two networks break! Now, we have two groups of nodes. In the group that has lost connection to the master, nodes start an election and pick up another master!

The clients which are outside the network can still see all nodes! Now, clients are actually communicating with two clusters each having its own state!

This definitely breaks the replicated log consistency. How exactly is it handled or should it be handled in Raft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Virtually every consensus protocol requires a majority of nodes to be available to elect a leader. In your example, there are two options:

1. When partitioning is happening, one of the networks will have a majority of total number of nodes - then this network will be able to elect a majority. E.g. one network has one node and the other has two - the second network may elect a leader as it has two out of three nodes.
2. When partitioning is happening, none of networks may have a majority, hence no leader will be elected. E.g. each network has two nodes - four nodes total and three nodes is required for majority; no leader will be elected in a case of partitioning

Comment: I actually mean, imagine a cluster with 500 nodes and imagine 250 in each partition (theoretically)

Comment: And these two partitions can coexist forever if not being noticed by the admins.

Comment: I always taught it's a bad idea that if the master goes down the whole cluster goes down with it, but after this problem I changed my mind. I think, the master should either predefined, or the next master should be known in advance. In this way the part of the cluster that is down will be inaccessible. Otherwise it will divide like a cellular system.

Comment: If there are 500 nodes, then the majority is 251. Typically the predefinition of leader won't help as deciding that the old leader is down and the new one is up still requires consensus. "if the master goes down the whole cluster goes down with it" - that's true for the duration of new election, which is more or less a consensus run. I don't think this is something possible to avoid. The key property of raft is "at most one leader exists" - such system is much simpler to reason about.

Comment: So do you mean that Raft guarantees there will be only one master (by detecting which network has the majority of nodes)? I am asking you because I read exactly the opposite elsewhere about Raft, I read that it has no ability to protect the cluster against partitioning but when the two partitions join, they will synchronize.

Comment: Yes, for sure at most one leader! The point of raft (and many other consensus based algs) to have a single leader to avoid any conflicts. It is much easier to avoid conflicts than resolve them. For example, let's say we have two leaders - one gets a command X=1 and the other X=2 - they won't be able to resolve the conflict. Strategies like Last Write Win are not good as they require clock synchronization.

Comment: But how exactly can it determine if it has the majority of nodes? What if I shutdown a large number of nodes intentionally?

Comment: Assume I shut down 251 nodes in the example I provided, now there is a cluster which is minority! so what happens to that?

Comment: It makes sense to read intro in https://raft.github.io/raft.pdf - it addresses both questions: what is consensus (with a preset number of nodes) and how to change a raft cluster config (e.g. replace nodes)